# SSL installed but no lock

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have open ssl installed on the server, all the key ,csr and crt on the server. Configured apache conf to the correct path for key and cert but i don't see a lock in the url(firefox 3.6.2).In chrome it shows https crossed out with red.Does this mean the certificate is not working properly? I have apache2 as the  web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tls provides both *encryption* and *authentication*.

Encryption means that outsiders are unable to read your traffic.

Authentication means that you are confident of the identity of the host your are communicating with.

If chrome crosses out the https, it means that you are using tls, and you have probably set up encryption properly, but chrome is not confident in the authentication of the server.  Typically, this is caused by an untrusted certificate; either the subject does not match, or the CA is not trusted.

If you are using a self-signed cert, then it's probably an untrusted CA.  Installing the CA into chrome should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem some time ago that I have installed the SSL certificate successfully but still it show cross on browser address bar, I found the issue was caused due to a image and a javascript file which was included as absolute HTTP url. I change absolute URL to relative and now both files were loading over HTTPS and browser show green bar.